# Spring 4.3.5 can i use runtime-generated java classes with @ModelAttribute annotation?

Tags: java, spring-4, modelattribute

I'm facing an MVC application based on Spring 4.3.5

When the user submits a form and the correct controller method call comes in, the @ModelAttribute annotation pulls the binded object from the model. 
Given the syntax of the @ModelAttribute annotation, the object type is specified into the method parameter definition, as for example

```
@ModelAttribute("command") Mail mail
@ModelAttribute("command") News news
```

etc.

For some functional reasons, the application creates java classes on the fly from xml descriptors via Castor framework. These classes do not exist at development-time  but exist only at run-time.

I can't find a way to use these runtime-generated-classes with the @ModelAttribute annotation! 
At the moment, i should develop new controller methods for every single object.

Does anyone has any idea or suggestions?

thx a lot in advance

Comment: You cannot use annotations with anything dynamic - that's a javac restriction. You could instead hook into the underlying AOP system that is using these annotations.

Comment: what do you mean? can you give me further suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to bind a request to a dynamically created object, provided it adheres to a POJO structure. There is an example (number 2) in [this blog post](http://www.codelooru.com/2010/11/how-does-modelattribute-work.html) that handles the exact same scenario.

The param type for the binding object need not be static. It can be as generic as java.lang.Object.

e.g.

```
@Controller
public class CommandController {

    @ModelAttribute("command")
    public Object getInitializeObject(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //use your own logic to instantiate the object.
        if(request.getParameter("requesttype").equals("mail")) {
            return new Mail();
        }
        else {
            return new News();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/myrequest.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(@ModelAttribute("command") Object command) {
        //request handling logic here.
    }

}
```